# A combinatorial property for finite cyclic groups

Tags: finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I was reading about the Cauchy–Davenport inequality and other results in combinatorics and the following property came to my mind.

Let $G$ be a finite group. I call here $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}\subseteq G$ a *$\pm$-subset* for $G$, if

1. the identity of $G$ is not contained in S and
2. any element $g$ of $G$ can be written as $g=s_{\sigma(1)}^{\varepsilon_1}\cdots s_{\sigma(n)}^{\varepsilon_n}$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and each $\varepsilon_i\in\{-1,1\}$.

For example, $\{\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}\}$ is easily seen to be a $\pm$-set for the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_5$. On the other hand, it is easy to see that for instance the cyclic group of order $2$ or $4$ do not have any $\pm$-subset. Finally, we may call *minimal* a $\pm$-subset if it does not contain properly any other $\pm$-subset for the same group.

I have looked for something like this in the literature, but I did not find anything.

Is something known about (minimal) $\pm$-subsets for cyclic groups of odd order?

Comment: So you are not allowing the exponents to be $0$?

Comment: Did you invent this property yourself?

Comment: @Randall, I haven't read about this property before, but I don't know if it's something new or not